# Javascript update functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting into game developing online. I am trying to make an online FPS game, and I've only gotten to the point where I need to update my character. I am trying to keep my code simple, using only a draw and update function. When the html loads, I execute both: (Is this necessary?)

```
<body onload='DRAW(); UPDATE();'>
```

The draw function draws the player to the screen, and the update is supposed to check for a keypress to move the character. I am trying to make the script update using this:

```
function UPDATE()
{
    update = setInterval(UPDATE, 60);
}
```

and to my knowledge, it is working fine because when I try and edit code in my online IDE (c9.io) which I use to test the site, it freezes when the site is running. I am also calling eventListeners in the draw function. (Is this proper if I want to test for a key down every frame?)

```
function DRAW()
{
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        keys.keys = (keys.keys || []);
        keys.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e){
        keys.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    });
}
```

**My questions are:**

- Is there an easier way to make a script update every frame?
- Is there    a JavaScript addon (like Three.js) I can use to make
  developing this    easier on myself?

Any knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This makes everything crash:

```
function UPDATE()
{
    update = setInterval(UPDATE, 60);
}
```

You are recursively creating a new interval every 60ms; the first time you call UPDATE, you create an interval that creates a new interval every 60ms. All newly create intervals do the same. Don't really know what you actually want to do here.

> I am also calling eventListeners in the draw function. (Is this proper
>   if I want to test for a key down every frame?)

It's fine to create eventlisteners in the draw function, provided you only call this function once. Which I guess you don't. Each time you call DRAW() a new set of eventlisteners will be added, and you really don't want that.

What you need is a form of game loop. Explaining how to create an FPS game is a bit more than I can do, but you can start by looking at this article [Anatomy of a video game](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Anatomy)

Comment: DRAW() should only be calling once in the <body onload> part of the HTML (to my knowledge), thanks for the info on the setInterval though. I knew it was crashing it, I just couldn't figure out why. I'll check on the article

Comment: @TaylorBrown Think of it as equivalent to a nuclear chain reaction. After running for just 960ms you already have 65536 intervals running in parallell, and it just keeps on doubling every 60ms. Your computer can't handle that, and the browser crashes.

Comment: Good analogy, makes a lot more sense now.